# Use same name twice for a variable and for a pointer(c programming)

Tags: c, variables, pointers, naming-conventions, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *i, int *j)
{
    int t;
    t = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = t;
}

void main()
{
    int i,j;
    i=5;
    j=10;
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    swap(&i,&j);
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);

}
```

Will there be any problem with this small programme which swaps two variables because i,j inside the function work as pointers and inside main contain numbers? should i have used another letters, e.g. a,b instead of i,j inside main?

Answer (score 4):

Variables are local to the scope they are defined, so no this should not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 4):

Variables only "live" inside the function you create them. In other words, the `i` in `main` is completely different from the `i` in `swap`.

Your code only incidentally references the same variable.

If the variable had been declared in the global scope (outside of any function) then you might have a problem.

So no, there's no problem at all in this case. Go wild (but not *too* wild; if things get too wild for you, or for anyone reading your code, consider changing the names...)

Comment: There's still no problem if a variable is global; the local one will shadow it.

Comment: Ah, yes, considering he declares it again. It's hard to tell how he would do it, but I'd think he wouldn't declare it again on purpose. I didn't mean to go that far with my answer, so I specified "If the variable had been declared in the global scope", and then I don't mention more variables. Shadowing has a price of its own, so I'd venture to say it might still create a problem,